# How can I get users to connect to my database if my server deny's remote access for allowing all i.p's (*.*) ?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database-connection, remote-access

I am making a web application, but I also want to make it a desktop application. The problem is that my server (for security purposes) does not allow remote access to connect outside of the server unless you manually import the i.p. addresses and this will not work because it needs to allow access to everyone...so what is the solution for this?

Is there anyway around this issue? Please help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: Write a middle tier object like a servlet that runs on a server with IP access to the database and funnel all desktop and web requests through it.  The servlet can also enforce basic auth or more for security.  It can bind and validate requests to avoid injection attacks.  Lots of benefits.

Comment: You can use a web service to expose "services" to and from your database.  This allows you to grant basic/advanced CRUD to DB objects, without ever exposing the actual DB (and DB credentials) to the outside world, just the services that work with the db.  Web API, WCF, REST, SOAP, are all ways to implement services.  I'm sure there are more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a proxy service that runs on a box with access to the DB server.  Your desktop application can consume the proxy service and the proxy service in-turn will access the database.

This is a fairly common design when you want to allow thick clients to access data in a centralized database.